# SF1 Lightning URL redirection/landing issues from Email

Tags: lightning-experience, email-template, landing-page, custom-url

I am trying out to figure out if I missing some configuration or if there is a workaround for this requirement to make it work as expected.

I have an email triggered from my apex controller which uses VF email template. In the email template I have the dynamic lightning URL for the record view. The logic works fine, but the issue is the URL in the email onclick redirects to login page -->on login it lands on Home page rather than redirecting to the record view. If the user is already logged in and I click the URL from email it works as expected i.e navigates to the record view.

Here is the URL format I have in my VF email template:

https://lightning.domain.com/one/one.app#/sObject/{!relatedTo.id}

Any thoughts or ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't need to do that; simply link to `https://mydomain.my.salesforce.com/{!relatedTo.Id}`. This link will work in both Classic and Lightning. For a user with Lightning enabled, alohaRedirect will take care of directing Lightning to the correct record, while a user in Classic will go directly to the Classic detail page.

Comment: Hi  sfdcfox, Unfortuntely even though I was sys admin and and was lightning enabled, using the https://mydomain.my.salesforce.com/{!relatedTo.Id} redirected me to classic page.

Comment: My apologies for not being clear.Works fine on desktop with mydomain.my.salesforce.com/{!relatedTo.id}. but in IOS it redirects to classic page